# What would be the correct design here (encapsulation, polymorphism, inheritance)?

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism, encapsulation

Assuming I have an interface and 3 or 4 classes that implement the interface. Now let's say I have another method but it is relevant only for one or two implementing classes.

So as I see it there are two approaches

1. Declare the method in the interface, implement in all the classes. In classes that the method is not relevant - throw "not supported" exception.
2. Declare the method only in the implementing classes where relevant but then you have to downcast the instance from interface type to the specific type in order to call the method.
   So would be your design here and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the [interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) here, part of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. Instead of having one large interface, split the interfaces up into a few smaller interfaces. Implement the interfaces only in the classes that need it.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a parent interface. Make the classes that satisfy the interface implement that interface. Create a second interface that extends the first one and adds the extra methods and then make the remaining classes implement that interface. You would still be coding to an interface rather than an implementation and all your design principles are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (not enough reputation to upvote)

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself this, will the object that consume **the interface** necessarily expect this function to be there? Is it important that **no matter which instance of the interface you pass**, you'll **still have that method available?**

If the answer to that question is yes, 1. If no, 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (not enough reputation to upvote)